# Regex pattern works in powershell but not in notepad++

Tags: command-line, powershell, notepad++, regex

I use the following line in  powershell, which finds what I am looking for.

```
Select-String -Path *.txt -Pattern '(.*)pov\"(.*)Fred(.*)\"$'
```

but I cannot get the find command in notepad++ to find anything.
Wrap around selected , Regular Expression Selected , Newline not selected
Is there some basic difference between the way these two systems use regex.

line example is:-             `pov" example text        Fred        "`

Comment: I can't reproduce this, it works for me. Did you remove the `'`s from the pattern?

Comment: the regex engine in notepad++ is PCRE, the one in PoSh is the dotnet engine with a few convenience tweaks [default to case _insensitive_, for instance].

Comment: Hey you forgot to accept my answer(click that tick icon):)

Comment: @Lee_Dailey: Just a remark, regex engine used by Notepad++ is [Boost](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_75_0/libs/regex/doc/html/), not [PCRE](https://pcre.org/). Nevertheless, that doesn't make a great difference.

Comment: @Toto - thank you! i managed to miss the switch from PCRE to Boost. [*blush*]

Answer (score 1):

I was able to reproduce the problem in Notepad++ 7.9.2 and I instantly solved it.

### ***How did I reproduce it***

Use `'(.*)pov\"(.*)Fred(.*)\"$'` (WITH single quotes), it returns error: `Find: Can't find the text "'(.*)pov\"(.*)Fred(.*)\"$'"`, which is correct.

[image]

### ***How did I solve it***

Just remove the single quotes and it will correctly find the matches:

[image]

### ***Explanation***

Regular expressions are treated as strings, in PowerShell texts enclosed in quotes (`'` and `"`) are treated as string objects, in most if not all programming languages
you need to explicitly use quotes to make a segment of text a string object.

However in Notepad++ everything you type is already treated as strings, so the quotes become literal quotes and part of the string, changing the meaning of the regex so there wouldn't be matches.

---

### ***Update per comment***

I tested it myself and I found that you don't need to use `fred` (lower-case), `Fred` (proper-case) works fine, Notepad++ is case-insensitive.

Proof:

[image]

Comment: Yip I was a complete idiot. Was doing this at 2.30 AM.

Comment: Just tried it again and it worked OK.  Say Fred was replaced by [fred].  I was trying \[fred\] should I just have used [fred] instead